# Use Excel Interop to grab image of Excel chart without writing to disk or using the clipboard

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

The [interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._chart_members(office.11,lightweight).aspx) to the chart object in Excel only allows access to the image representing the chart through two methods:

- export, which saves the image to a file
- CopyPicture, which saves the image to the clipboard

Both of these options are problematic (saving to a file is really slow, and saving to the clipboard could clobber user data).

Is there a better way to do this? The only way I can think of is to use to create a temporary ram disk and mount it under say '%TEMP%\tmp_ram_disk\' so that the save-to-disk option won't be slow, but sure how to do that or if it's even possible. This is a C# project.

Answer (score 0):

One option that may work would be to use a memory mapped file.  Of course disk can be involved there, so you should profile the standard export to disk vs. using a memory mapped file (assuming the slowness of disk i/o is your only concern with that approach). 

  They don't have out of the box support in .Net yet, but there likely plenty of implementations out there.

Comment: The Export method only accepts a filename as a string. If I have a memory mapped file as an object in my program, will the operating system be aware of it when _Chart.Export("%TEMP%\chart.png") is called?

Comment: My intuition says yes, windows would be smart enough, but then again I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can load an Excel workbook and return an image from a chart with a few lines of code:

```
namespace GetChartImage
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Open the workbook.
            var workbook = SpreadsheetGear.Factory.GetWorkbook(@"t:\tmp\Chart.xlsx");
            // Get a chart named "Chart 1" on the sheet named "Sheet1".
            var chart = workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"].Shapes["Chart 1"].Chart;
            // Get a System.Drawing.Bitmap image of the chart.
            var bitmap = new SpreadsheetGear.Drawing.Image(chart).GetBitmap();
            // Save it to a file and launch just to see that it worked.
            bitmap.Save(@"t:\tmp\Chart.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"t:\tmp\Chart.png");
        }
    }
}
```

SpreadsheetGear does not support every Excel charting feature (yet) but you can see a representative sample of what it can do in the live ASP.NET "Dynamic Chart Gallery" sample [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/charting.aspx), or you can download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx) and try it yourself.

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC