# manage excel with c#

Tags: c#, excel, charts

I need to edit *.xls* files, draw charts and save them as an image. I found 2 tools at the moment:

- [**Aspose .Cells:**](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx) I can do all what I need but the license is too expensive.
- [**epplus:**](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) I can't save drawed charts in an image file.

**My question is:** are there other libraries which do what i'm looking for?

Comment: Using the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace is a pretty good way.  Why are you looking for something else?

Comment: COM interop is not that easy to manage and work with. Also, it is not recommended for server environments either.

Answer (score 1):

SpreadsheetGear is awesome and quick as hell. However, if you want a free solution, why don't you use the following namespaces

```
using Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

these can be included after you add the following COM references 'Microsoft.Office.Core' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel'. Using 'System.Reflection' you can then expose much of Excel's functionality including graphics etc.

The 'Graphs' facilities can be exposed using

```
[InterfaceTypeAttribute()]
[GuidAttribute("0002086D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
public interface Charts : IEnumerable
```

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.charts.aspx) for specific details. But a simple example of a basic plot would be

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

class Program
{
    const string fileName = "C:\\Book1.xlsx";
    const string topLeft = "A1";
    const string bottomRight = "A4";
    const string graphTitle = "Graph Title";
    const string xAxis = "Time";
    const string yAxis = "Value";

    static void Main()
    {
        // Open Excel and get first worksheet. 
        var application = new Application();
        var workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets[1] as 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet;

        // Add chart.
        var charts = worksheet.ChartObjects() as 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObjects;
        var chartObject = charts.Add(60, 10, 300, 300) as 
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ChartObject;
        var chart = chartObject.Chart;

        // Set chart range.
        var range = worksheet.get_Range(topLeft, bottomRight);
        chart.SetSourceData(range);

        // Set chart properties.
        chart.ChartType = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlChartType.xlLine;
        chart.ChartWizard(Source: range, Title: graphTitle, CategoryTitle: xAxis, 
            ValueTitle: yAxis);

        // Save.
        workbook.Save();

        // Dispose objects.
        worksheet.Dispose();
        workbook.Dispose();
        application.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Editing Excel files is done is a similar fashion. See [this MSDN post](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084) for more information.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The problem is that Office is required to use these functions. And in my context, it is a problem because i couldn't have Office installed!

Comment: I see... Appologies for the miss direction.

Answer (score 0):

I am working with the excelent library called [Spire](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/excel-for-net-introduce.html).
I think it can save draw charts, but I never checked it.

Please look at the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716221/use-excel-interop-to-grab-image-of-excel-chart-without-writing-to-disk-or-using) , it's not related to some library ,
just using interop.

Comment: No it's not possibile: [see there](http://www.e-iceblue.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2483)

Comment: Answer updated. Please look above

Comment: Thank's, SpreadsheetGear for .NET seems what i need but it's not free :( ! However the license is less expensive then Asopse .Cells!